# How to style the Loginform of silverlight Business application

Tags: silverlight, authentication, wcf-ria-services

I am using SL4 Business application with WCF RIA service. In my app, there is a loginForm. in the designer of loginform I can found username textbox and password textbox.But in .Xaml page its like the code given below.

```
 <local:BusyIndicator x:Name="busyIndicator" BusyContent="{Binding Path=Strings.BusyIndicatorLoggingIn, Source={StaticResource ApplicationResources}}"
                         IsBusy="{Binding IsLoggingIn}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <toolkit:DataForm x:Name="loginForm"
                              Padding="10,0,10,0"
                              CurrentItem="{Binding}"
                              IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoggingIn, Converter={StaticResource NotOperatorValueConverter}}"
                              AutoEdit="True" CommandButtonsVisibility="None" HeaderVisibility="Collapsed"
                              AutoGeneratingField="LoginForm_AutoGeneratingField"
                              Style="{StaticResource LoginDataFormStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </local:BusyIndicator>
```

My question is I need to style the username textbox as well as password textbox in the dataform. How can I do this? From where can i access these controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those controls are generated by the DataForm control. You basically need to put a default style for TextBox and PasswordBox under the root Grid's Resources. I gave them a massive font size of 50. You just need to replace them with your own styles.

```
<!-- LoginDataForm Style -->
<Style x:Key="LoginDataFormStyle" TargetType="dataControls:DataForm">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="370"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoCommit" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateFields" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="DescriptionViewerPosition" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="LabelPosition" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderVisibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="dataControls:DataForm">
                <Grid dataControls:DataField.IsFieldGroup="True">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>                    
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="PasswordBox">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>                    
                        </Style>
                        <Style x:Key="ButtonGeneric" TargetType="Button">
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

The form automatically generates the fields for you (the `AutoGenerateFields` property is set to `True` by default). However, in the case of the LoginForm in the Silverlight Business Application template, the form has a handler for the `AutoGeneratingFields` event (`LoginForm_AutoGeneratingField` as shown in your xaml). In this handler, the username textbox and the password box are created, databound and added to the form. You can jump in there and do the customization you want by setting their properties.

Hope this helps :)